# root path changed while include the file one in another in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi I include one file in to another one in angular js.

I have folder structure like below

```
|__ image
    |__ image.jpg
|__ top.html
|__ detail
    |__ detail.html
```

Ex:

```
top.html

<img src="image/image.jpg" />
```

this one shows the image correctly.

I included this `top.html` file in `detail.html`

so the image not showing because of including the file one in another which is inside the folder.

If I want to call the image in detail.html then I can call like below

```
<img src="../image/image.jpg" />
```

But I included the file `top.html` which have the image, so the problem.

can anyone help to so the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path : `/image/image.jpg` will refer to the same location wherever you are located.

An absolute path will begin with a slash that refers to the server root.